# How to detect the Program Files folder inside my executable?

Tags: visual-c++, setup-project, setup-deployment

My problem is, currently, all the references inside my program are using `C:\\Program Files\\Myprogram` folder. Is there a way that I can make my program is installable at any machine regardless where is their `Program Files` folder is located.

This is because some machine, has the folder at other drive eg. `D:\Program Files`, at Win7 machine has different name for its Program Files folder.

Need advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, hard-coding file system paths is a *very* bad practice, for precisely this reason. They are subject to change on different machines, and your problem shouldn't be the least bit affected because of it.

You need to use [environment variables](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560744.aspx) instead. The one for the "Program Files" folder is quite simple and easy to remember. It is simply:

```
%PROGRAMFILES%
```

The Windows API provides a set of functions to retrieve the locations of these special folders, as well. Investigate the [`SHGetFolderPath` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181.aspx) (or [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188.aspx), assuming you only need to target clients running Windows Vista and above). You will need to specify the CSIDL value for the Program Files folder, `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES`. The complete list is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494.aspx).

Sample code:

```
TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, NULL, 0, szPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Visual C++ .NET, you can use [`GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

```
// Sample for the Environment::GetFolderPath method
#using <mscorlib.dll>

using namespace System;

int main() {
   Console::WriteLine(S"GetFolderPath: {0}",
      Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::ProgramFiles));
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has about a half dozen different answers to this question. I believe the one they favor at the moment is [`SHGetKnownFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). Depending on how old of Windows versions you care about, you may also want to look at [`SHGetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762204%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your program in C/C++, you can use the SHGetFolderPath function as specified at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762181(VS.85).aspx. Vista and newer have newer APIs, but this one is still around for backward compatibility.

From a Visual Studio command prompt, you can build and run this to try it out.

```
// Build with:
// cl sample.cpp /link Shell32.lib

#include <stdio.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>

void main()
{
  char path[MAX_PATH];
  HRESULT hr = SHGetFolderPath(
    0,                   // hwndOwner
    CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES, // nFolder
    0,                   // hToken
    SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT,  // dwFlags
    path);               // pszPath
  if (hr == S_OK)
    printf("Program files at\r\n%s", path);
  else
    printf("failed to get folder");
}
```